# VITA - Linq to SQL - where object is nothing

Tags: vb.net

I am currently testing out [VITA: Application Framework](http://vita.codeplex.com/) and have one Entity called Company. A company can have child companies e.g. different offices / stores but I only want to the parent companies in a list.

So far I have the below to get the records from the database but the where clause gives me this error

```
Unknown column 't0$.*' in 'where clause'
```

Code to get parent companies

```
DatabaseConfig.Configure(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Context").ConnectionString)
Dim rbApp = DatabaseConfig.App
Dim dbSession = rbApp.OpenSession()
Dim companies As IList(Of ICompany) = dbSession.EntitySet(Of ICompany).Where(Function(w) w.Parent Is Nothing).ToList()
```

Below is the Interface for Company

```
<Entity, ClusteredIndex("CreatedOn,Id")>
Public Interface ICompany

    <PrimaryKey, Auto>
    Property Id() As Guid

    <Auto(AutoType.CreatedOn)>
    Property CreatedOn() As DateTime

    <Size(200), Index>
    Property Name() As String

    <Size(100), Nullable>
    Property Telephone() As String

    <Size(100), Nullable>
    Property Mobile() As String

    <Size(100), Nullable>
    Property Fax() As String

    <Size(250), Nullable>
    Property Email() As String

    <Nullable>
    Property DeleteOn() As DateTime?

    <OneToMany(), Nullable>
    Property Parent() As ICompany

    <OrderBy("Name:DESC")>
    Property Children() As IList(Of ICompany)

End Interface
```

Comment: Why don't you report this at the project's site? We can't do anything with bugs here.

Answer (score 0):

Not a bug with VITA. I removed the OneToMany attribute and the query worked as expected.

Comment: I don't know VITA, but to me it does look like a bug because you do have a one to many association, but the self-reference seems to be a problem. Does VITA still populate the Children now?

Comment: I have opened a ticket with the DEV and he is currently trying to replicate the issue but yes the parent and child records are being populated.